# can we redirect Status of previous command into another variable

Tags: bash, shell

can we redirect Status of previous command into another variable?
like:
echo hello
s=echo $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign it:

```
echo hello
myVariable=$?
echo "Previous echo exit code is $myVariable"
```

`$?` is just a variable, like any other—the only magic is how it is "automagically" set.